# fopen(c:\dorian.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, fopen

HOW IS THIS DUPLICATE?
The solution in "can-i-read-a-txt-file-with-php" does not work for me, because the code itself is fine, the error is because of the file path, I've tried different approaches, that's why I came here, to get some help.
I tried the code that's on there anyway, still the exact problem;
Warning: fopen(C:\dorian.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\filestats\index.php on line 9

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for C:\dorian.txt in C:\xampp\htdocs\filestats\index.php on line 10

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\filestats\index.php on line 10

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\filestats\index.php on line 11

I'm trying out this simple code on PHP, I can't figure out what the trouble is.
I'm trying to read what's in the file.

Here's the code.

```
<?php
$fpath = "C:\dorian.txt";
$handle = fopen($fpath, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($fpath));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

I also tried with dorian.txt in a different directory, copy-pasted it from file properties.

Comment: can you move this txt file to htdocs folder ?

Comment: I've tried the \\ instead of \ as well, doesn't work.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Moved it to htdocs, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes, for Windows this will look like:

```
<?php
$fpath = "C:\\dorian.txt";
$handle = fopen($fpath, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($fpath));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

I believe you can also use forward slashes instead.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Yeah, it tried the slash thing, alternating between everything, still doesn't work. I'm learning from php.net, actually.

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions in relation to whatever is running your PHP script? Also what is the output of "echo ini_get("open_basedir")"